# What does this notation mean in a nuclear reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, notation

> $$\rm ^9Be (\alpha, n) {}^{12}C$$

What does this notation mean in a nuclear reaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ${}^9\rm{Be}$ (Beryllium nucleus with $4$ protons and $5$ neutrons, so atomic mass $9$) can react with
- an $\alpha$ particle (Helium nucleus with $2$ protons and $2$ neutrons)

to produce

- ${}^{12}\rm{C}$ (Carbon nucleus with $6$ protons and $6$ neutrons) and
- $\rm{n}$ ($1$ neutron).

Another way of writing this is: ${}^9_4\rm{Be} +{}^4_2\rm{He} \to{}^{12}_6\rm{C} +{}^1_0 \rm{n}$